# Why is $U(12) = U_{4} (12) ~ U_3(12)?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, abelian-groups

Why is $U(12) = U_{4} (2)~ U_3(12)$

**Attempt:** Any subgroup $U_k(n) = \{x \in U(n)~~|~~x \mod k=1 , k ~|~n \}$

Hence : if $U(12) =\{1,5,7,11\}$

then : $U_4(12) =\{1,5\}$ and $U_3(12)=\{1,7\}$

We see that $U_4(12) ~U_3(12)= \{1,5\} \{1,7\} = \{1,5,7,11\} = U(12)$

I have already proved this using the fact that $U_t(st) \approx U(s)$ and that $U_t(st),U_s(st)$ are disjoint from each other when $\gcd (s,t)=1$

But, does there exist a more elementary proof not necessarily using isomorphism . I tried a modular arithematic proof but it's proving to be too tedious and not going anywhere.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Anyone got any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"More elementary proof"...than the one you've produced? This is a very basic fact and you've already proved it in a basic way...and modular arithmetic kicks in in the fact that both subgroups are isomorphic to each other and to cyclic group $\;C_2\;$ .

"Another" way, I guess, you could do it: it's easy to check that $\;U(12)\cong V:=C_2\times C_2=$ the Klein group (non-cyclic of order four), and what you've shown above *in fact* is that the product of $\;U_3(12)\;,\;\;U_4(12)\;$ is (isomorphic to) their direct product as they're clearly normal and their intersection is trivial, thus you've in fact that

$$U(12)=U_3(12)\times U_4(12)=U_3(12)U_4(12)$$

Perhaps you could also be interested in remarking that $\;U_3(12)\,,\,U_4(12)\cong C_2\;$ ...and whatever you use, at the bottom line you will **have** to use something from group theory as this is a group theoretic question.

Comment: Thank you. Well, actually, I was looking for a confirmation that group theory needs to be used here in some way or the other. Initially, it just seemed that just modular arithmetic will solve the problem, because it was just a question of getting remainder $1$ when divided by the factors of $n$.

It's still a little intriguing how sometimes only the higher concepts come in handy